# How to use clflush?

Tags: c, caching, assembly, timing

I want to measure the time difference between accessing a table entry and accessing another entry after a clflush.
 Below you will find my attempt, I get almost no penalty for the above two operations. The table is of length 256 with 8 bits in each entry. I suspect my clflush is not working properly. I am compiling with -O3 flag in gcc.

```
            #include <stdio.h>
            #include <stdlib.h>
            #include <stdint.h>
            #define ARRAYSIZE(arr) (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]))

            #define REPEAT 10000

            unsigned char table[256]={103,198,105,115,81,255,74,236,41,205,186,171,242,251,227,70,124,194,84,248,27,232,231,141,118,90,46,99,51,159,201,154,102,50,13,183,49,88,163,90,37,93,5,23,88,233,94,212,171,178,205,198,155,180,84,17,14,130,116,65,33,61,220,135,112,233,62,161,65,225,252,103,62,1,126,151,234,220,107,150,143,56,92,42,236,176,59,251,50,175,60,84,236,24,219,92,2,26,254,67,251,250,170,58,251,41,209,230,5,60,124,148,117,216,190,97,137,249,92,187,168,153,15,149,177,235,241,179,5,239,247,0,233,161,58,229,202,11,203,208,72,71,100,189,31,35,30,168,28,123,100,197,20,115,90,197,94,75,121,99,59,112,100,36,17,158,9,220,170,212,172,242,27,16,175,59,51,205,227,80,72,71,21,92,187,111,34,25,186,155,125,245,11,225,26,28,127,35,248,41,248,164,27,19,181,202,78,232,152,50,56,224,121,77,61,52,188,95,78,119,250,203,108,5,172,134,33,43,170,26,85,162,190,112,181,115,59,4,92,211,54,148,179,175,226,240,228,158,79,50,21,73,253,130,78,169};



            inline void clflush(volatile void *p)
            {
                asm volatile ("clflush (%0)" :: "r"(p));
            }

            inline uint64_t rdtsc()
            {
                unsigned long a, d;
                asm volatile ("cpuid; rdtsc" : "=a" (a), "=d" (d) : : "ebx", "ecx");
                return a | ((uint64_t)d << 32);
            }

            inline int func(int *a) { 
                int i;
                for(i=0;i<REPEAT;i++){
                    a[i]=(int)table[rand()%256];
                }

            }
            void flushCache(unsigned char *start)
            {
                // flush table
                unsigned char* fPtr = (unsigned char*)start;
                clflush(fPtr);
                clflush(fPtr+64);
                clflush(fPtr+128);
                clflush(fPtr+192);
                clflush(fPtr+256);
            }


            inline void test()
            {
                int i=0;
                uint64_t start, end;
                char c;
                int temp[REPEAT];

                start = rdtsc();

                func(temp);

                end = rdtsc();

                //following line of code to prevent compiler from optimizing. do something with the return value
                for(i-0;i<REPEAT;i++){
                temp[i]=temp[i]+temp[i/2];
                }

                printf("%ld ticks\n", end - start);
            }

            inline void testflush()
            {
                int i=0;
                uint64_t start, end;
                char c;
                int temp[REPEAT];

                start = rdtsc();

                func(temp);
                flushCache(table); //flush afer every read

                end = rdtsc();

                //following line of code to prevent compiler from optimizing. do something with the return value
                for(i-0;i<REPEAT;i++){
                temp[i]=temp[i]+temp[i/2];
                }

                printf("%ld ticks\n", end - start);
            }



            int main(int ac, char **av)
            {
                test();
                printf("Tables in cache!\n");
                testflush();
                printf("Tables evicted from cache.\n");
                test();

                return 0;
            }
```

update : I understand ther might be some problem due to table access. Here is another code that evicts a single variable instead of the whole table. This one shows significant inclrease in clock cycle when using the clflush(). Does it mean clflush() is working properly and the incrased time is due to access the variable from memory?

```
            #include <stdint.h>
            #include <stdio.h>
            #define REPEAT 100000
            inline void clflush(volatile void *p)
            {
                asm volatile ("clflush (%0)" :: "r"(p));
            }

            inline uint64_t rdtsc()
            {
                unsigned long a, d;
                asm volatile ("rdtsc" : "=a" (a), "=d" (d));
                return a | ((uint64_t)d << 32);
            }

            volatile int i;

            inline void test()
            {
                uint64_t start, end,clock;
                volatile int j;
                long int rep;
                int k;

                clock=0;
                for(rep=0;rep<REPEAT;rep++){
                    start = rdtsc();
                    j = i+1;
                    end = rdtsc();
                    clock=clock+(end-start);
                    k=j;
                }
                printf("took %lu ticks\n", clock);
            }

            inline void testflush()
            {
                uint64_t start, end,clock;
                volatile int j;
                int k;
                long int rep;

                clock=0;
                for(rep=0;rep<REPEAT;rep++){
                    start = rdtsc();
                    j = i+1;
                    end = rdtsc();
                    clflush(&i);
                    clock=clock+(end-start);
                    k=j;
                }
                printf("took %lu ticks\n", clock);
            }


            int main(int ac, char **av)
            {
                i=5;
                printf("------------------------------------------\n");
                test();
                printf("------------------------------------------\n");
                testflush();
                printf("------------------------------------------\n");
                test();
                return 0;
            }
```

Comment: `clflush(fPtr+256);`? Note: there is no reason for `fPtr`.

Comment: ok. Then how should I do it?

Comment: @user2764478: Yes, (for the 2nd version) a significant increase in cycles would imply `clflush` is working.

Comment: Aside from you having a few lines of inline assembly, I can't see how this is an assembly question

Answer (score 1):

Some issues I see with the code.

You end the timer for `testflush` after calling `clflush`. Therefore you are timing the cycles necessary for processing these instructions, too. I don't think that is intended.

In your test function you have a loop with 10000 iterations. Each iteration may invoke a reference to one new cache line, but there are only 4 cache lines in `table`. So at least 9996 iterations invoke no cache miss anyway.

Thus you are timing 10000 times `rand()%256` plus 4 cache loads. Even if cache loads take a few hundred cycles, 10000 iterations of `rand()%256` will still overshadow that.

These 10000 integers generated must also be written back. I am not sure whether L1->L2 cache bandwidth would be a limiting factor, but it might be.

You also need to run the test a few thousand times or so and average, the sample variance is way too high otherwise.

Then it might also be possible that the cpu prefetches the cache lines again by speculation before you request them. It is allowed to do so, but I don't know how clever current cpus are.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have another added another code, which does not measure the time for clflush(). This code shows a significant decrease in efficiency when using with clflush()(by almost a factor 4). Can you please check whether this decrease in efficiency is happening due to flushing?

Comment: @user2764478 Your updated code takes about 50% longer with clflush on my system. The rdtsc instructions seem to take about as much time as the cache miss. However you have removed the cpuid instruction, which I think means that the tick count will be less reliable. Adding it the cache miss is completely overshadowed again.

Comment: inline uint64_t rdtsc()
    {
        unsigned long a, d;
        asm volatile ("cpuid; rdtsc" : "=a" (a), "=d" (d) : : "ebx", "ecx");
        return a | ((uint64_t)d << 32);
    }

Comment: Can you please check with the previous rdtsc code? and change repeat to 1900000.

Comment: With the above changes I can see an increase in the timing with clflush instruction.

Comment: @user2764478 As I already said, with cpuid I cant see any significant difference on my system, probably because cpuid; rdtsc takes much longer that the cache miss. This may very well be completely different on your system.

Comment: Ok, Now I am wondering what may be the reason? I just want to benchmark  the difference between reading a value directly from memory(clflush()) and reading a value from cache.