# Issues with CLFLUSH()?

Tags: c, performance, caching, timing

Can you please tell me how to use the clflush() instructions? I have written the following simple code to measure the difference between a execution time of reading a variable from cache and after evicting it from cache. However I did not find conclusive results. What is the correct way to evict a cache using clflush()?

```
            #include <stdio.h>
            #include <stdint.h>
            #include"cpucycles.c"

            #define REPEAT 1900000
            inline void clflush(volatile void *p)
            {
                asm volatile ("clflush (%0)" :: "r"(p));
            }

            inline uint64_t rdtsc()
            {
                unsigned long a, d;
                asm volatile ("cpuid; rdtsc" : "=a" (a), "=d" (d) : : "ebx", "ecx");
                return a | ((uint64_t)d << 32);
            }

            volatile int i;

            inline void test()
            {
                uint64_t start, end,clock;
                volatile int j;
                long int rep;
                int k;

                clock=0;
                for(rep=0;rep<REPEAT;rep++){
                    start = rdtsc();
                    j = i+1;
                    end = rdtsc();
                    clock=clock+(end-start);
                    k=j;
                }
                printf("took %lu ticks\n", clock);
            }

            inline void testflush()
            {
                uint64_t start, end,clock;
                volatile int j;
                int k;
                long int rep;

                clock=0;
                for(rep=0;rep<REPEAT;rep++){
                    start = rdtsc();
                    j = i+1;
                    end = rdtsc();
                    clflush(&i);
                    clock=clock+(end-start);
                    k=j;
                }
                printf("took %lu ticks\n", clock);
            }


            int main(int ac, char **av)
            {
                i=5;
                printf("------------------------------------------\n");
                test();
                printf("------------------------------------------\n");
               testflush();
                printf("------------------------------------------\n");
               test();

                return 0;
            }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use clflush?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39448276/how-to-use-clflush)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your 'flush' time is being overwhelmed by the rest of the code.  Also, as written your non-flush executes fewer lines of code (no flush), making comparisons "unfair."

How about something more like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <emmintrin.h>

#define REPEAT 1900000

volatile int i;

inline void test(void *v)
{
    uint64_t start, end;
    volatile int j;
    long int rep;
    int k;

    start = __builtin_ia32_rdtsc();
    for(rep=0;rep<REPEAT;rep++){
        j = i+1;
        _mm_clflush(v);
        k=j;
    }
    end = __builtin_ia32_rdtsc();
    printf("%p took %lu ticks\n", v, end-start);
}

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    void *v = malloc(1000);
    i=5;
    printf("------------------------------------------\n");
   test(v);
    printf("------------------------------------------\n");
   test((void *)&i);
    printf("------------------------------------------\n");
   test(v);
   free(v);

    return 0;
}
```

This way we are always flushing something, but one test affects your global, and the other doesn't.  It also doesn't use any inline asm.

Built with -O3, this gives me times like 149 for non-flush and 312 for flush.